# Syncing data over server using Volley

Tags: java, android

I want to sync my data with server with at least more than 10 pictures at a time using Volley's StringRequest but within 15 to 20 seconds its ignore uploading and I get the log

```
D/Volley: [5122] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request=<[ ] https://....
```

Comment: Can I suggest you switch over to using Retrofit - `https://github.com/square/retrofit`? The community support for it is much higher and you will have an easier time finding docs and guides for it.

Comment: Is it? Would this disturb my current app's sequence and data?

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the time out duration for volley

```
myRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
        MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS, 
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, 
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

Comment: I tried but not worked for me. I have tried almost all possible solutions but not worked. :(